# OpenCV cv::Mat with external data pointer causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am writing a program in C++ that uses OpenCV. OpenCV version is 3.3.0 and platform is Linux.

I am creating cv::Mat object using an external data pointer as follows:

`Void * FrameDataPtr = new unsigned char[FrameHeight * FrameWidth * 3];
cv::Mat Frame(FrameHeight, FrameWidth, CV_8UC3, FrameDataPtr, CV_AUTOSTEP);`

The cv::Mat is created successfully. `Frame.data` is same as `FrameDataPtr`. But as soon as `Frame` is used, the program crashes with a segmentation fault. Even a simple operation like `Frame.setTo(0)` causes crash.

Is there any way to find the cause of this problem and resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the `CV_AUTOSTEP`.

Comment: That solved the problem! Thanks!